# Is there a way to standardize mongosh JSON output?

Tags: json, mongodb, jq, mongo-shell

MongoDB upgraded their command-line interface (formerly *mongo*, now *mongosh*).  Before, the *mongo* command output was in proper JSON, the kind *jq* could ingest.

For example:

```
{ "abc" : "hello" }
```

The new *mongosh* command now outputs stuff like:

```
{ abc: 'hello' }
```

...which can't be parsed by *jq*.

Is there a way to standardize *mongosh* to output standard JSON?

If not, is there any shell command that filters "incorrect but coherent" JSON (from stdin) and normalizes it into a standard form (to stdout)?

Comment: Try `JSON.stringify` or `EJSON.stringify`

Comment: What do you do with jq? I am asking because you can do everything also in mongosh directly - really everything, mongosh is a full Node.js shell.

Answer (score 1):

A MongoDB employee recommends using the `EJSON.stringify` wrapper, e.g.:

```
$ mongosh [...] --eval "EJSON.stringify(db.adminCommand('listDatabases'))"
```

Except for extensions such as `Long(_)` and `Date(_)`, it looks like `hjson` could also be used.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap your queries inside `EJSON.stringify` from inside `mongosh` console.
Eg: if you want to run the query `db.books.find({"book-id":"123456789"})` execute the following.

```
EJSON.stringify(db.books.find({"book-id":"123456789"}).toArray(), null, 2, { relaxed: false })
```

Answer (score 0):

In principle you can use `JSON.stringify()`. However it has some limitations, see this example:

```
x = {
  a: 1,
  b: ISODate("2022-03-26T11:15:53.750Z"),
  c: Int32(1),
  d: Long("1"),
  e: Long("2"),
  f: Decimal128("-7.6E+11"),
  g: 1.345,
  h: 2,
  t: 'foo'
}

JSON.stringify(x, null, " ")
{
 "a": 1,
 "b": "2022-03-26T11:15:53.750Z",
 "c": 1,
 "d": {
  "low": 1,
  "high": 0,
  "unsigned": false
 },
 "e": {
  "low": 2,
  "high": 0,
  "unsigned": false
 },
 "f": {
  "$numberDecimal": "-7.6E+11"
 },
 "g": 1.345,
 "h": 2,
 "t": "foo"
}
```

`Date` objects are converted into strings.

An alternative could be `EJSON.stringify()`, which recognizes data types like `Date`. It is also mentioned in [documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/mongodb-shell/reference/compatibility/#--eval-behavior):

> `EJSON` has built in formatting options which may eliminate the need for a parser like `jq.`

However, the values are printed as `{"$date": "2022-03-26T11:15:53.750Z"}`

```
EJSON.stringify(x, null, " ")
{
 "a": 1,
 "b": {
  "$date": "2022-03-26T11:15:53.750Z"
 },
 "c": 1,
 "d": 1,
 "e": 2,
 "f": {
  "$numberDecimal": "-7.6E+11"
 },
 "g": 1.345,
 "h": 2,
 "t": "foo"
}
```

My solution is a customized function. `tojson` and `tojsononeline` do not exist anymore in `mongosh`, so I created my own:

```
if (typeof tojsononeline == 'undefined') {
   function tojsononeline(x) {
      return EJSON.stringify(x)
         .replace(/\{"\$date":"(.{19,23}Z)"\}/g, "ISODate(\"$1\")")
         .replace(/\{"\$oid":"(\w{24})"\}/g, "ObjectId(\"$1\")")
         .replace(/\{"\$numberDecimal":"(.+?)"\}/g, "Decimal128(\"$1\")");
   }
}

tojsononeline(x)
{"a":1,"b":ISODate("2022-03-26T11:22:08.029Z"),"c":1,"d":1,"e":2,"f":Decimal128("-7.6E+11"),"g":1.345,"h":2,"t":"foo"}
```

There are a few more data types used in MongoDB, however I think they are hardly relevant. Otherwise add a few more `replace()` operations.

Anther solution is to install "mongosh snippet", either with `snippet install mongocompat`, or download scripts from https://github.com/mongodb-labs/mongosh-snippets/tree/main/snippets/mongocompat and run

```
load('mongonative.js');
load('mongoassert.js');
load('mongotypes.js');
```

Preferable put these 3 lines in your `.mongoshrc.js` file.

These 3 scripts define (almost?) all function from legacy `mongo` shell which are not (yet) available in new `mongosh`

Be aware, when you move to new `mongosh`, then your application may face some more differences, see for example [mongosh Data Types](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/mongodb-shell/reference/data-types/)